# Как уменьшить радиус ripple-эффекта у BottomNavigationView?

Tags: java, android, xml, bottom-navigation-view

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот пример того про что я спрашиваю. Я не знаю как называется этот серый кружок который появляется во время нажатия, но мне надо сделать его меньше. Пожалуйста, помогите.

Элемент BottomNavigationView:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color"
        android:outlineProvider="none"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemIconSize="40dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

bottom_nav_color.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/black" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/black"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте свой ресурс `drawable/my_ripple.xml`, в котором укажите желаемый цвет и размер ripple-эффекта:

```xml
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#ebaeba"
    android:radius="24dp" />
```

И задайте атрибут `app:itemBackground` для `BottomNavigationView`:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    ...
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/my_ripple" />
```

Обратите внимание, что тег `ripple` работает с 19 версии API (Android 4.4 и выше).

Comment: Всё заработало как часы, спасибо большое